# using const in C++ getters and setters

Tags: c++

I've found out this is how getters and setters are implemented in C++:

```
class Foo
{
     X x_;
public:
          X & x()       { return x_; }
    const X & x() const { return x_; }
}
```

Still I don't quite understand it.

Well the setter is somewhat clear: it returns a reference to x_ and we can make this reference point to whatever value of type X passed to the method.

The getter is way too hard to read. It also returns a reference of type X (but a constant reference?) and the method itself is declared const. What is the point in making it const? The reference returned by it is already const, that's, we won't be able to use this getter as the setter above, the first const won't let it happen. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Try removing the `const` from the second overload - oops, it won't compile. Try removing the second overload entirely, then try `const Foo foo; X x_copy = foo.x();`.

Comment: Using that kind of getter/setter, you may as well just have the member variable be public.  Consider this instead:  `X x() const { return x_; }` and `void set_x(X value) { x_ = std::move(value); }` ... that kind of setter can also have value validation and invariant checking, or a good place to set a breakpoint, or a place to using Boost Signals2 to signal all observers that the value has changed.

Comment: Quite frankly in this particular case I'd just use a struct as you are exposing the internal variables 100% anyway.

Comment: I would call both of those functions "getters" because they get (a reference to) the member. Neither version involves setting anything. A "setter" should *set* the member, as in `void x(const X & new_value) { x_ = new_value; }`.